# Where do I stand on a misdiagnosis when I've already paid for the repair and driven the car home?

Tags: alternator, repair, power

last week I couldn't get my car to start I had it towed to a national known Auto repair chain they had it for five days couldn't figure it out.  so I had a towed to another shop when I called and the mechanic? wanted to know what it was wrong with it and I told him it was losing power intermittedly while driving. He said we can take care of that bring it on in.when I towed.the vehicle into his shop.I had written down all the history for the past 6 months of what I've done what I had done, no opinions whatsoever it just facts he said he didn't need that he said it's losing power right and I said yes and he said we'll figure it out we don't need that.24 hours later I get a call it's your alternator I said okay, go ahead with the repair. I didn't think it was that but I didn't tell him that cuz I was basing everything on fact and I don't know enough about cars to question someone who is professionally trained to do so.after the repair i went picked up my car,  seem like the electric part was working better but there was a buzz from I don't know if it's the speaker for the radi.regardless I drove it home, next day I go down to the store about a mile away come out about a half hour later won't start. call a friend for a jump we didn't jump it and we ended up getting it to start without one.the key wouldn't turn for a minute there, which was bizarre but the long and short of it is what do I do about the alternator that I just paid $600 for? based on what I've seen I don't think I needed one? where do I stand? How do I approach it without sounding like I'm telling someone that they don't know how to do their job? Cuz that's not the case I just think they needed a little more information that wasn't gathered.

Comment: $600 for an alternator? If that is 600 USD, you got completely ripped off there. Just google for the alternator price for your car.

Comment: Did not read - please format so it is not a wall of text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this more of a legal question than about maintenance/repair.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, if you don't know much about cars, then your careful logs of what you know isn't much good to the mechanic.  It ends up being a travelogue of ramblings and incoherency.  *Um, much like your question*.

Your single best bet when it comes to keeping cars maintained is to have mechanical knowledge.   That, plus a set of tools, also gives you a 60-90% discount on most auto repairs :)